# SQL referencing same table twice

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have been tinkering with SQL to develop a database for a business and I have a table which is referring to another table by its primary keys, but doing so twice for different reasons. Can I do this, and more importantly should I do this?

So let's say we fix cars for other companies and we have a database of every car we work on. We fix cars for a company called Lots-o-Rental Cars, and another called Cool Cars.

Now while Cool Cars has a selection of their own cars, they also have a deal with Lots-o-Rental Cars to borrow some of their cars. There are instances when we will charge Lots-o-Rental Cars for work we do on a car, but other times we will charge Cool Cars for work done on the same car.

My current set up (simplified here) looks a bit like this:

**Table:** company

**Columns:** company_id (pk), company_name

1, Lot-so-Rental Cars

2, Cool Cars

**Table:** branch *(used to show multiple business locations for the same company)*

**Columns:** branch_id (pk), company_id (fk)

1, 1

2, 1

3, 2

**Table:** cars

**Columns:** car_id (pk), car_brand, car_model, owner_id (fk), on_hire, hiree_id (fk)

*'owner_id' and 'hiree_id' are both branch_id's from the branch table.
'on_hire' is a value to determine true or false if the car is currently hired out to another company we service.*

1, Ford, Mustang, 1, YES, 3

2, VW, Beetle, 1, NO, NULL

3, Nissan, Pulsar, 2, NO, NULL

4, Chevrolet, Camaro, 3, NO, NULL

Using this layout, can I select car_brand, car_model, owner_id (displayed as company_name), and if the car is hired out also show hiree_id (displayed as company_name)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. It's perfectly valid to have two different foreign key columns (**`owner_id`** and **`hiree_id`**) in the same table (**`car`**) reference the same table (**`company`**).

It's fine to do this as long as the "domain" for each of the foreign keys is the same. (The "domain" is the set of allowable values for the column.) Where you run into trouble is where you want to allow (as an example) "Cool Cars" to be a "hiree" but not allow it to be an "owner". Then, it's non-trivial for the database to enforce that kind of constraint.  As long as every row in **`company`** can be a valid reference from both "hiree" and an "owner", then it will be fine.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** What SQL statement would I use to display car_brand, car_model, company_name AS "Owned by" and company_name AS "Hired by"?

**A:** Your SELECT statement would need to make two references to the `company` table.

And since references to the columns from the two references to `company` table within the query will ambiguous, we have to **qualify** the column references, and at least one of the references to the company table will require us to assign an **alias** to disambiguate the references. (This is an example that illustrates our pattern of *always* assigning an alias to a table reference in a query, and qualifying all column references.)

```
SELECT c.car_brand
     , c.car_model
     , o.company_name AS `Owned by`
     , h.company_name AS `Hired by`
  FROM `cars` c
  LEFT
  JOIN `company` o
    ON o.company_id = c.owner_id
  LEFT
  JOIN `company` h
    ON o.company_id = c.hiree_id
 ORDER BY c.car_brand, c.car_model, o.company_name, h.company_name
```

**FOLLOWUP**

My apologies. I entirely missed the `branch` table. The query would require to references to that table as well.

```
SELECT c.car_brand
     , c.car_model
     , o.company_name AS `Owned By`
     , h.company_name AS `Hired by` 
  FROM cars c
  LEFT
  JOIN branch bo
    ON c.owner_id = bo.branch_id
  LEFT
  JOIN company o
    ON bo.company_id = o.company_id 
  LEFT
  JOIN branch bh
    ON c.hiree_id = bh.branch_id
  LEFT
  JOIN company h 
    ON bh.company_id = h.company_id
 ORDER
    BY c.car_brand
     , c.car_model
     , o.company_name
     , h.company_name
```

Comment: Makes sense.

So what command/s would I use to display car_brand, car_model, company_name AS "Owned by" and company_name AS "Hired by"?

Comment: Alright, cool. I can understand all of that.


However, in this instance it doesn't work because a company_id is not equal to an owner_id or hiree_id. It needs to go through the branch table.


So I'm struggling to make the join where cars.owner_id or cars.hiree_id equals branch.branch_id, and then branch.company_id equals company.company_id

Comment: I seem to have figured this out for myself now: 
SELECT ... o.company_name AS 'Owned By', h.company_name AS 'Hired by'   FROM cars AS c  LEFT JOIN branch AS bo  ON c.owner_id = bo.branch_id  LEFT JOIN company AS o  ON bo.company_id = o.company_id  LEFT JOIN branch AS bh  ON c.hiree_id = bh.branch_id  LEFT JOIN company AS h  ON bh.company_id = h.company_id  ORDER BY ... o.company_name, h.company_name

Comment: @James V:  Sorry about that, I missed the `branch` table.

Comment: @spencer7593 Is there any disadvantage of this? Why one should not take this approach. In out prod DB, there are millions of rows in a table, but for handling a case (which is not more than 10 as of now), either I can create one more table with the above logic or alter existing table, and create another table. Logic for handling the case will be different in both and I thought creating table with two keys pointing to id of same table would be fine.

Comment: @VivekVardhan: There's no disadvantage (that I'm aware of)  to having two (or more| foreign keys in one table referencing the same target table. As I noted in my answer, one thing I would take into account is that the list of valid values would be the same for those foreign key columns. (Sometimes, a foreign key implements a relationship to an entity. Sometimes, a foreign implements a lookup to a "list of valid values" rather than a relationship to an entity.)

Comment: this helped me a lot, thanks for detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

Referring to primary key twice for this scenario seems fine to me. One possible alternative is getting rid of `on_hire` since `hiree_id == NULL` basically means not `on_hire`. And you should be fine for getting the information you want.

Comment: Thanks for that. Typing it out made me realise that on_hire would be a redundant column.